# How to call default layout in ZF2 for all modules or selected modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have developed dashboard.phtml in my module Admin/view/layout/dashboard.phtml

Now I have developed another module like restaurants now I want to use dashboard.phtml in all action of restarunts module I tried below.

my module.config.php

```
 'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/default' => __DIR__ . '/../../Admin/view/layout/dashboard.phtml'
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'restaurants' => __DIR__ . '/../view',

    ),
```

my indexaction of restaurantsController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{

   $viewModel = new ViewModel();
   $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/default');
   $restaurant_info_array = array();
   $restaurant_info = $this->getRestaurantsTable()->fetchAll();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($restaurant_info as $ri)
    {
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['id'] = $ri->id;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['name'] = $ri->name;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['published'] = $ri->published;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['email'] = $ri->email;
        $is_menu_available = $this->getRestaurantsTable()->getRestaurantsMenu($ri->id);
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['res_menu'] = count($is_menu_available);
        $i = $i+1;
    }

    $viewModel->setVariables(array(
            "restaurants"=>$restaurant_info_array
    ));
```

it is not working please help me if I call dashboard as my default layout for my admin side modules it will be great coz It is not logical same dashboard.phtml lies in all folders of my modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found the solution I change my code as below in module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{ 
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
   //added lines for layout
    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $controller->layout('layout/default');
    });
}
```

change in my indexAction.

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $viewModel = new ViewModel();
   $restaurant_info_array = array();
   $restaurant_info = $this->getRestaurantsTable()->fetchAll();
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($restaurant_info as $ri)
   {
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['id'] = $ri->id;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['name'] = $ri->name;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['published'] = $ri->published;
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['email'] = $ri->email;
        $is_menu_available = $this->getRestaurantsTable()->getRestaurantsMenu($ri->id);
        $restaurant_info_array[$i]['res_menu'] = count($is_menu_available);
        $i = $i+1;
    }

    return $viewModel->setVariables(array(
            "restaurants"=>$restaurant_info_array
    ));

}
```