# Zend Layout in ZF2

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

How can we set default layout in zf2 if the layout folder is out side the module directory

[image]

Comment: can you check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837841/how-to-call-default-layout-in-zf2-for-all-modules-or-selected-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the layout anywhere you want it doesn't have to be in the modules directory.

just set it inside your modules config

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => '/anypath/you/want/view/layout/layout.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
       '/anypath/you/want/view',
    ),
),
```

Comment: just starting with zf2,   i have two module album and user which module.config.php(in album or user) should i choose to set the default one? i can see this code as  'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',

Answer (score 0):

As per the question posted the answer  by @Andrew is correct .

When i notice the working of layout in zf2 i came to certain conclusion

1. Able to set the layout folder anyway in application environment
2. Only one layout is taken for all the modules , the layout taken is from the last module mentioned in application.config.php

For example

```
  'modules' => array(
        'Album',              
        'Testlist',
        'Customer',
        'Application',
        'User',

    ),
```

Then the user layout will be taken .

if we have only one layout in the application this  will be fine

To switching between layouts in the module  came across
http://www.webtrafficexchange.com/zf2-configure-layout-each-module-edpmodulelayouts
which seems to be useful

Answer (score 0):

The default layout is `layout/layout` configured in the view manager.